# Convert string to html

Tags: grails, gsp

I've currently got a string that is stored as html. When I output this to the gsp page I just get plain text.

```
<g:each in="${fixtureInView.links}">
    <h1>Link :${it.encodeAsHTML()}</h1>
</g:each>
```

Currently displays `Link :&lt;a href=&#39;http://www.google.co.uk&#39;&gt;Google&lt;/a&gt;`

and if I change it to decodeHTML it shows `<a href='http://www.google.co.uk'>Google</a>`

When I try just `${it}` I get `Link :&lt;a href=&#39;http://www.google.co.uk&#39;&gt;Google&lt;/a&gt;`

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you like the `decodeHTML` version? What result are you expecting?

Comment: I'm wanting the link to appear as it would if you wrote the html on the gsp page but it just shows ot as text.

Answer (score 9):

I've figured this out. If you place `raw()` round the variable that is html code, it will let the raw html be rendered as html and not as a string.

Comment: but be sure to controll the content properly or else you might create a security problem

Comment: Good advice! Fortunatly its only a little project im doing for uni so it doesn't matter too much.

Comment: https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2013/11/grails-goodness-generating-raw-output.html In case someone is looking for example.

Answer (score 0):

In list save your link like this.

```
"<a href=\"google.com\">Google</a>"
```

And print it like this.

```
<g:each in="${fixtureInView.links}">
            <h1>Link :${it}</h1>
 </g:each>
```

It will work for you.

Comment: how would this been done with two variables for the website and text? Currently i have `"<a href='" + params["link${i}"] + "'>" + params["name${i}"] + "</a>"`

Comment: Can you show your controller code for more clarification?

Comment: `def linksArray = []
        
        for(int i=0; i < params.linkCount.toInteger()+1; i++)
        {
            if (!params["link${i}"].equals("") || !params["name${i}"].equals(""))
            {
                linksArray << ('<a href=\"' + params["link${i}"] + '\">' + params["name${i}"] + '</a>').encodeAsHTML()
            }
        }`